# How to add a second legend with different units for the same variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plotted air temperature in Kelvins with the code below. Now I want to add a second legend showing the equivalent values in degrees Celcius. Is it possible?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cptcity)

nc <- rotate(brick(x = fnl_20111128_00_00.nc,
                   var = "TMP_1000mb")))
df <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(nc))

ggplot() + 
  geom_raster(data = df,
              aes(x = x, y = y, fill = X1322438400),
              interpolate = T) +  
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = cpt("ncl_precip2_17lev"), 
                       name = "T (K)",
                       na.value = "white")
```

[image: Here is the wanted result.]

Comment: Would you also consider showing labels containing both sets of units in the same legend? I think that would be simpler to achieve, e.g. something like `scale_fill_gradientn(..., name = "T (K / C)", labels = function(x) paste(x, "/", round(x - 273.15)))`.